# How to collect a List<Foo> to a Map<Bar, List<Baz>> using Java lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, collectors

I have an object `Foo` that has references to `Bar` and `Baz` objects:

```
public class Foo {
    private Bar bar;
    private Baz baz;

    public Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz) {
       this.bar = bar;
       this.baz = baz;
    }
}
```

I have a `List<Foo>` that I'd like to convert into a `Map`.  I'd like the key to be `Bar` and the value to be a `List<Baz>`.

I can create a `Map` where `Bar` is the key and the value is a `List<Foo>`:

```
Map<Bar, List<Foo>> mapBarToFoos = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getBar));
```

I don't know how to take that last step and turn the value List into a `List<Baz>`.  Is there a lambda conversion on the value that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want

```
list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Foo::getBar, 
    mapping(Foo::getBaz, toList())));
```

Where `getBaz` is the "downstream collector" which transforms the grouped `Foo`s, then yet another which creates the list.

Comment: Right idea you just need to pass a downstream collector to the `mapping`

Comment: Finally got to try it - worked like a charm.  Others were equally sage in their advice, but you were first.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're close, you'll need to supply a "downstream" collector to further refine your criteria. in this case the `groupingBy` approach along with a `mapping` downstream collector is the idiomatic approach i.e.

```
list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Foo::getBar, mapping(Foo::getBaz, toList())));
```

This essentially works by applying a `mapping` downstream collector to the results of the classification (`Foo::getBar`) function.
basically what we've done is map each `Foo` object to `Baz` and puts this into a list.

---

Just wanted to show another variant here, although not as readable as the `groupingBy` approach:

```
foos.stream()
    .collect(toMap(Foo::getBar, v -> new ArrayList<>(singletonList(v.getBaz())),
            (l, r) -> {l.addAll(r); return l;}));
```

- `Foo::getBar` is the `keyMapper` function to extract the map keys.
- `v -> new ArrayList<>(singletonList(v))` is the `valueMapper`
  function to extract the map values.
- `(l, r) -> {l.addAll(r); return l;}` is the merge function used to
  combine two lists that happen to have the same `getBar` value.

Answer (score 2):

To change the classic `grouping` to a `Map<Bar, List<Foo>>` you need to use the method which allows to change the values of the map :

- the version with a downstream [Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, downstream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)
- which is a mapping operation [Collectors.mapping(mapper, downstream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)
- which requires another operation to set the container [Collectors.toList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--)

```
//Use the import to reduce the Collectors. redundancy
//import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<Bar, List<Baz>> mapBarToFoos = 
         foos.stream().collect(groupingBy(Foo::getBar, mapping(Foo::getBaz, toList())));

//without you'll get
Map<Bar, List<Baz>> mapBarToFoos = 
         foos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getBar, Collectors.mapping(Foo::getBaz, Collectors.toList())));
```